# Are French postmodernism, American Critical Theory and their heirs collectivist theories?

Tags: postmodernism, critical-theory

Is it correct to affirm that French postmodernism (Foucault, Derrida, Deleuze, etc.), and American Critical Theory (Adorno, Marcuse, etc.), and their heirs such as gender and postcolonial studies (Butler, Saïd) are collectivist theories (in contrast to individualistic theories: John Stuart Mill, Alexis de Tocqueville, Adam Smith); in the sense that they emphasize the group, the collective, over the individual, in their understanding of sociological phenomena?

Comment: not really no. adorno is usually considered an individualist. they tend to be more marxist and less liberal, i guess. i suppose if you consider property right the core feature of individuality.

Comment: @anonymous What is marxism if it is not a collectivism?

Comment: that's quite a broad question. the critical theorists you mention are often called "individualist" and they are more marxist than the others. it would be wrong to assume that the more influenced by marx a philosopher is the more collectivist they are.

Comment: @anonymous My question on whether these theories are collectivists is not underlied by the assumption that these authors have marxists tendencies (the link between marxism and these theories as far as I understood is very complicated), but by the assumption that they understand social phenomena almost exclusively through ideas such as social system, social constructs, structures, etc.

Comment: sorry i think you know too much i don't for me to help at all. what about those ideas make them collectivist, rather than, say, idealist?

Comment: @anonymous "what about those ideas make them collectivist, rather than, say, idealist?" Well, I also personally feel they are idealists (if you know more about them being idealists, don't hesitate to inform me, it is an interesting issue). But in any way, one can be collectivist **and** idealist, don't we?

Comment: yes, that sounds possible. post modernism is closely allied ideologically to anti realism, critical theorists nominalism, and gender etc. theory is anti essentialism. can we think of that as an idealist thread? marxists are anti "idealist" in that they think the working class will respond to social conditions, but personally i would consider marxism a response to collectivism, rather than variant of it. [YMMV](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36687/given-marxs-original-theory-of-alienation-why-is-he-interpreted-as-being-anti)

Comment: @anonymous From https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36687/given-marxs-original-theory-of-alienation-why-is-he-interpreted-as-being-anti: First, following Hegel, the Marxist picture is such that the whole is the real. "In the Hegelian picture, this whole is "spiritual" but in the marxist version it's somehow merely a material whole. Consequently, the individual is not of prime importance as in views like existentialism. Instead, the individual is a part of something larger." This to me suffices to say that marxism is collectivist. And I don't mean it in a pejorative sense.

Comment: @anonymous May we continue this discussion in a chat?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to, really I know very little about any of this. +1 for being inquisitive!

Comment: @anonymous Just would like to pursue the discussion on these theories and idealism especially